# ASP.NET session randomly reused when using iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, session-cookies, sessionid

I have a scenario like this:

An ASP.NET form `WebForm1.aspx`, which contains an iFrame to `WebForm2.aspx`, and code to trace the current `SessionId`.
An ASP.NET form `WebForm2.aspx`, which contains code to trace the current `SessionId`.

As someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533709/session-id-changing-randomly) suggested, I do this in each page load, and in `Global.asax` (Session_Start):

```
Session["dummy"] = "dummy";
```

The web.config is configured like this:

For testing purposes I created two Windows Forms applications, which do the following:

1) Call the WebForm1.aspx from one single WebBrowser control 10 times.

2) Call the WebForm1.aspx from 10 different WebBrowser controls, each a single time.

The results are:

1) Always the same SessionId in WebForm1 as well as in WebForm2.

2) Multiple SessionIds are generated:

```
Form1: ixbahucx3wmii452xlgserk5
Form1: wqh5dwsyovnnwclkfvanlj30
Form1: vddeexb1bfmo4uqw5qjdjol4
Form1: bavcxrgtaz5hvzswlabnuefy
Form1: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
Form1: pjtiez5dmxldfoojmflsbf1u
Form1: znf0qq41bmsccbjqcdpulefp
Form1: bml5vvj13c22yj0agfua5gyk
Form1: lzdufc3y55tqci0gtfgmpq33
Form1: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
Form2: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
Form2: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
Form2: znf0qq41bmsccbjqcdpulefp
Form2: znf0qq41bmsccbjqcdpulefp
Form2: lzdufc3y55tqci0gtfgmpq33
Form2: lzdufc3y55tqci0gtfgmpq33
Form2: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
Form2: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
Form2: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
Form2: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
```

What is the reason, that some SessionIds in WebForm1 do not have a corresponding one in WebForm2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET uses cookies to keep SessionId.

When request already contains `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie, ASP.NET uses Session ID value from cookie to restore (OR to create, in case of time out) Session object on server side.

When request doesn't contain `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie, ASP.Net creates new Session object, generates new Session ID for it, and sends `Set-Cookie` header with Session ID value with response.

So basically if browser already has cookie values set, or has processed `Set-Cookie` header from previous response, it will use it to send next request, and 'old' session will be reused; otherwise new session will be created.

Case 1 shows this pretty good.

Case 2 is more complex, but looks like you start all 10 requests simultaneously, and browser controls shares the same cookie storage.

First ten requests generates ten completely different sessions, as they don't have cookies set:

```
(1) Form1: ixbahucx3wmii452xlgserk5
(2) Form1: wqh5dwsyovnnwclkfvanlj30
(3) Form1: vddeexb1bfmo4uqw5qjdjol4
(4) Form1: bavcxrgtaz5hvzswlabnuefy
(5) Form1: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
(6) Form1: pjtiez5dmxldfoojmflsbf1u
(7) Form1: znf0qq41bmsccbjqcdpulefp
(8) Form1: bml5vvj13c22yj0agfua5gyk
(9) Form1: lzdufc3y55tqci0gtfgmpq33
(10) Form1: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
```

Next, requests one by one started to respond by server, and each will contain `Set-Cookie` header (as all requests didn't have SessionID cookie). Each new of these `Set-Cookie` will overwrite previous one, and browsers will request `Form2` from iframe with newly set sessionId. One by one below:

received response from (5), sent 2 requests before next response:

```
(11) Form2: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
(12) Form2: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
```

received response from (7), sent 2 requests before next response:

```
(13) Form2: znf0qq41bmsccbjqcdpulefp
(14) Form2: znf0qq41bmsccbjqcdpulefp
```

received response from (9), sent 2 requests before next response:

```
(15) Form2: lzdufc3y55tqci0gtfgmpq33
(16) Form2: lzdufc3y55tqci0gtfgmpq33
```

received response from (10), sent 3 requests before next response:

```
(17) Form2: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
(18) Form2: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
(19) Form2: nch1bocb0obw3tfi0rnz4fa4
```

this request sent after response to (5), but response received just now:

```
(20) Form2: v2rhzfjwoptmhfpbm2qzzfgh
```

Comment: Do I have a chance to somehow circumvent this behaviour, or is the use of sessions not suitable in this scenario?

Comment: Depends on what you trying to achieve. You can create new question and describe what you want to do.